# Why getReference instantly generates select

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using spring with JPA + Hibernate while I'm calling getReference or getOne from JpaRepository there is called select but all values still stay null. How can I stop select from being called. I want to be abble to just directly add link using references without fetching them. Mapping of entities is based off http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional-with-link-entity

Entitity

```
@Entity(name = "Parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval =  true)
private List<ParentChild> children = new ArrayList<>();

public void addChild(Child child){
    ParentChild parentChild = new ParentChild(this,child);
    this.children.add(parentChild);
    child.getParents().add(parentChild);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if ( this == o ) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) {
        return false;
    }
    Parent u = (Parent)o;
    return Objects.equals( id, u.id );
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash( id );
}
}
```

Service function

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void linkChildToParent(Integer childId, Integer parentId){
        Parent parent = em.getReference(Parent.class,parentId);
        Child child = em.getReference(Child.class,childId);
        parent.addChild(child);
}
```

Both references call select before I access any of their properties.

Comment: clearly em.getReference should not be calling the database at any point, and doesn't with the JPA provider I use (not Hibernate). Perhaps if you posted the SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

Could you add public `getId` method to `Parent` and `Child` classes, move `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations to these methods and try again?

According to Java Persistence with Hibernate book calling any method on proxy that is not "identification getter" will trigger initialisation of the proxy and hit the database.